# How to get the sum of children values of an object in a Javascript react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

Here is my object:

```
 var obj = {
  "idtransact1":  {

    "amount": 3000,

  },
  "idtransact2":  {

    "amount": 3000,

  }
}
```

I am trying to get the sum of all amount.
I tried to adapt this example but since it is not the same data structure then i am a bit lost.

```
var array = [{
  "adults": 2,
  "children": 3
}, {
  "adults": 2,
  "children": 1
}];

var val = array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return {
    adults: previousValue.adults + currentValue.adults,
    children: previousValue.children + currentValue.children
  }
});
console.log(val);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The key is to use `Object.values(obj)` to turn it into an Array first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `.reduce()` to get the sum:

```js
const data = {
  "idtransact1":  { "amount": 3000 },
  "idtransact2":  { "amount": 3000 }
};

const result = Object.values(data).reduce((r, { amount }) => r + amount, 0);
                   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach` loop

```js
var obj = {
  "idtransact1":  {

    "amount": 3000,

  },
  "idtransact2":  {

    "amount": 3000,

  }
}
var sum=0;

Object.values(obj).forEach((x)=>sum+=x.amount)
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

A for in loop is your friend when it comes to looking for values in an object.

```
var obj = {
    "idtransact1": {"amount": 3000},
    "idtransact2": {"amount": 3000}};

 var sumAmount = 0;
 for(var char in obj){
     sumAmount += obj[char].amount;
 }
console.log(sumAmount);
```

For your second example, the for in loop works the same way with the array of objects.

```
var array = [
    {"adults": 2,"children": 3}, 
    {"adults": 2,"children": 1}];

 var sumAdults = 0;
 var sumChildren = 0;
 for(var char in array){
     sumAdults += array[char].adults;
     sumChildren += array[char].children;
 }

 console.log(sumAdults + " " + sumChildren);
```

Less to remember if you can look for data in objects and data in an array of objects the same way. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
Array [
  Object {
    "product": Object {
      "cat_id": "20",
      "cat_name": "Pizza",
      "detail": "Pizza sauce, Green pepper & mozarella cheese",
      "discount_price": "",
      "has_extra": "0",
      "has_variation": "1",
      "id": "46",
      "image": "chicken-tikka-piza-recipe-main-photo.jpg",
      "name": "Chicken Fajita",
      "prep_time": "30",
      "price": "310",
      "status": "1",
      "time_stamp": "2021-01-02 19:43:41",
      "ven_id": "6",
    },
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "product": Object {
      "cat_id": "20",
      "cat_name": "Pizza",
      "detail": "Pizza Sauce, Tomato Green Paper, Olives Mashrooms And Chipotle Sauce with  extra Creamy mayoneese",
      "discount_price": "",
      "has_extra": "0",
      "has_variation": "0",
      "id": "45",
      "image": "chicken-tikka-piza-recipe-main-photo.jpg",
      "name": "Chicken Tikka",
      "prep_time": "15",
      "price": "310",
      "status": "1",
      "time_stamp": "2021-01-02 19:41:56",
      "ven_id": "6",
    },
    "quantity": 3,
  },
]
```

How to calculate its total price where quantity is not the same also I want to calculate total price